# Accuracy of categorical classification on my own photos get better?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I tried classification using my own photos “0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9” like MNIST.
But the accuracy doesn’t go well.. The following program is anything wrong?
If you find something, please give me some advice.

accuracy: 0.1000

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
#(80, 28, 28, 1)
#(20, 28, 28, 1)

print(y_train)
print(y_test)
#[7 5 4 2 8 8 0 1 8 7 4 7 3 4 2 5 2 2 5 3 0 4 9 1 9 0 5 7 6 6 8 0 1 0 8 0 2
# 8 9 9 4 7 4 0 6 1 1 2 1 9 6 7 4 3 7 4 9 4 0 8 5 2 3 8 1 9 3 7 3 5 4 2 3 1
# 0 9 6 0 6 8]
#[9 6 6 5 2 1 7 1 8 5 6 6 5 2 3 3 5 3 7 9]

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

history=model.fit_generator(
    datagen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32),
    steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // 32,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_train,y_train,verbose=2)
#80/1 - 0s - loss: 107.2582 - accuracy: 0.1000
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi i dont think you applied one hot encoded your labels for y_train and y_test

```py
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# convert to one-hot vector
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
```

Comment: Not if `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, like here.